# Reset all stock status in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

The stock statuses from my woocommerce installation were uploaded by another plugin (square) and so all goods are in stock even if they have quantity 0. Is there a way to get the statuses to reset somehow, so that products with 0 stock, have the stock status "out of stock".

I have looked for this and found the following [function](https://gist.github.com/codearachnid/5943589)

```
function jolie_theme_child_reset_stock_status(){
global $wpdb;
// set all status for products with 0 or less stocked quantity
$sql = "UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta stock, (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_stock' AND meta_value < 1 ) id SET stock.meta_value = 'outofstock' WHERE stock.post_id = id.post_id AND stock.meta_key = '_stock_status';";
// set all status for products with stock.
$sql .= "UPDATE $wpdb->postmeta stock, (SELECT DISTINCT post_id FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_stock' AND meta_value > 0 ) id SET stock.meta_value = 'outofstock' WHERE stock.post_id = id.post_id AND stock.meta_key = '_stock_status';";
// run queries
$wpdb->query( $sql );
}
```

But if I run this it causes a server 500 error. What is a simple way to reset the stock statuses with or without using the above code?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following sql command in your database using PHP my admin or anyother DB editor

```
Update wp_postmeta Set meta_value = 'instock' Where meta_value = 'outofstock' And meta_key = '_stock_status'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below query for update Woo-commerce product status change manually.

Query:-

`Update wp_postmeta Set meta_value = 'instock' Where meta_value = 'outofstock' And meta_key = '_stock_status'`

Note:-
First check your table name before run this query. If your table name prefix not default then change it.